# saiku application stuck at loading instead of loading login page

Tags: saiku

I have downloaded saiku biserver community edition and unzipped the file. i have started using start-saiku.sh file. then tried login at http:localhost:8080. The page is stuck at loading page instead of the opeinig login page. any help is appreciated. thank you